# Detect collision between 3 objects?

Tags: swift, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm trying to create an enemy AI, and I'm trying to check if the enemy's AI range collides with a wall before colliding with the player, so the enemy stops chasing the player when that happens.
[image: advanced drawing skills]

But it seems that I can only detect a collision between A and B, and not C. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: This is really a geometry problem of "how do I calculate intersections between line segments and planes?" combined with a programming problem of "how do I efficiently store information on objects, planes, and other geometric information for my program?"

Comment: Could you specify better the problem. Is it 2D or 3D? What are A, B and C? How do you store the coordinates for each player? How to you store information about walls?